# Non-moderate words

Tags: pronouns

What is a non-moderate word and are there grammar rules for the treatment of such words? For example, are italics never used for emphasis with "everything," which I've been told is an example of a non-moderate word?

Comment: I haven't heard of a non-moderate word. Do you mean a superlative? That's the most extreme of a class, like biggest, smallest, loudest, smartest, and so on.

Comment: What @rajaj9 said. Using [***immoderate** words*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22immoderate+words%22) could mean speaking without thinking, inciting rash actions, or using profanity, for example. But I don't know what ***non-moderate** words are* either.

Comment: No, not superlative. I suppose it could be compared to the concept of strong and weak endings in poetry. The idea that two stressed syllables are a strong ending and two unstressed syllables are a light ending. So that "desert" would be a light ending and "walk there" would be a strong ending. Of course, it's not sound but meaning that would define "non-moderate words."

Comment: I'm not "getting-it." Is *nothing* also a non-moderate word, or does it depend on usage such as "So" preceding many spoken replies? Are these "non-moderate" words exclusionary such as, always, never, nothing, and thus extremes by their use?

Comment: If you could tell us whether the term "non-moderate word" is one you made up or whether you have ever seen it written in a grammar book, that would be helpful. Especially if you could say what the grammar book was.

Comment: It was a term used by a translator and possibly a translation of a German or Japanese word. I will inquire further.

Comment: Apparently it's a term the translator has coined for words that are freighted with emotion or all encompassing. For example: evil, best, strong, weak, tall, love, hate, worst, none, me, you. The idea is that words like this should never be italicized because they are already emphatic.